# How to plus 2 JTextField numbers?

Tags: java, numbers

I want to add two numbers and put the result into a *JTextFields* (textboxes). Why doesn't this code work?

```
 public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
        private JButton plus;
        private JLabel text;
        private JTextField textbox1;
        private JTextField textbox2;
            public Okno(){
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            this.setBounds(400,400,400,400); 

            plus = new JButton("+");
            text = new JLabel("");
            plus.addActionListener(this);
            textbox1 = new JTextField("      ");
            textbox2 = new JTextField("      ");
            this.add(text);
            this.add(textbox1);
            this.add(textbox2);
            this.add(plus);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           if(e.getSource().equals(plus)){
               int result = Integer.valueOf(textbox1.getText()) +        Integer.valueOf(textbox2.getText());
              text.setText(Integer.toString(result)); //gtregergregergergreg
         }
          }
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Comment: Window or Okno?

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you remove spaces while putting numbers to the text fields, otherwise you get NumberFormatException. By the way don't use spaces for aligning the text fields. You can use `setColumns` or different layout manager. Also you should validate input to be sure there are just numbers, if you want to add them together.

Answer (score 0):

Delete spaces from:

```
textbox1 = new JTextField("      ");
textbox2 = new JTextField("      ");
```

cause while parsing to Integer it fails.
Set prefered size of textbox1 and textbox2:

```
 textbox1 = new JTextField();
 textbox1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
 textbox2 = new JTextField();
 textbox2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
```

Hope I helped :)